# Image wont show on visual studio design time

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis

I have a **virtual directory** on my **iis** *-portal*, which contains images. I put an image tag in my asp.net form.

```
   <img src="http://localhost/portal/images/button_right.gif" alt="Alternate Text" />
```

This is the code:

```
<%Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication15.WebForm1" %>    
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
    <head runat="server"> 
        <title></title> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <form id="form1" runat="server"> 
        <div> 
            <img src="http://localhost/portal/images/button_right.gif" alt="Alternate Text" /> 
        </div> 
        </form> 
    </body> 
    </html>
```

The image shows when I run the project, on the browser.
The image doesnt show in design time. - I see X, instead of an image.
I set all read write execute permissions alowed o the virtual directory.

Comment: I tried your question and it worked fine on my computer. virtual directory img pointing to e:\img, img src=http://localhost/img/1.png shows in vs designer? Did you try calling src path in a browser - just to check anything is setted up correct?

Answer (score 3):

You should never specify image src as an absolute path. Use `~` to address your application path. It requires the `runat="server"` attribute since it is substituted by IIS at server.

```
<img runat="server" src="~/images/button_right.gif" alt="Alternate Text" />
```

Comment: I think in this question the matter is to share images among applications. So you have to save them on same kind of shared directory (here virtual directory on iis) to be able to access those images on different webSites. Anyways in general you are totally right, always try to use relative paths.

Comment: Yes, seems like my post should be a comment, not an answer.